# Python: how do I compare two lists (username & password) read from a .txt to a user input

Tags: python, authentication

I have written a code that is supposed to request a user to input a username and password. The program should then open a .txt file containing a list of usernames and passwords and check to see if the entered entries are valid against username and password database in the .txt file. This is the first time I am posting here so please advise what else you would require. I have hopefully attached my .py file and .txt file.

I am able to input the first username and password, but the second one, I have to input twice in order for it to be successful. I'm sure that is due to the for loop, but then I do not know how else to do the compare the inputs with the username and passwords stored in the .txt

```
#======== User Login ====================

#read the use.txt
username_reg = []
password_reg = []
i = 0
username_list = []
password_list = []

with open('user.txt', 'r+') as f:           #open user.txt
    for line in f:                          #Now we reading user.txt
        line = line.replace(" ", "")        #replace space before password with no space
        line = line.replace("\n", "")       #remove the next line character as this will take a space in the list
        line = line.split(",")              #separate user name and password
        username_reg = line[0]
        password_reg = line[1]
        username_list.append(username_reg)
        password_list.append(password_reg)
#List check      
print(username_list)
print(password_list)
print(len(username_list))

username = input("Please enter username: ")
password = input("Please enter password: ")

for i in range(len(username_list)):
    if username == str(username_list[i]) and password == str(password_list[i]):
        print('''Please select one of the following options:
                r - register user
                a - add task
                va - view all tasks
                vm - view my tasks
                e - exit''')
        break

    while username != str(username_list[i]) and password != str(password_list[i]):
        print("invalid username or password")   
        username = input("Please enter username: ")
        password = input("Please enter password: ")
        i += 1

print("Great success")
```

Comment: I forgot to add the user.txt file is in the format:
admin, adm1n
abc, defg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this in a different way. Dictionaries work great when it comes to associate some specific data to a entity. In this case, I would use one to associate the password to each username.

Considering that your database stores the info as follows:

```
user1, password1
user2, password2
user3, password3
```

Then we can perform the following operation:

```
content = {}

with open('db.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.read().splitlines():
        user = line.split(', ')
        content.update({user[0]: user[1]})

username = input("Please enter username: ")
password = input("Please enter password: ")

if password == content[username]:
    print('''Please select one of the following options:
                r - register user
                a - add task
                va - view all tasks
                vm - view my tasks
                e - exit''')
```

We are basically opening the file, reading its lines (by using the `splitlines()` function of the `str` class), and the iterating over each line, separating the username and the password (by using `split(', ')` because ', ' is the separator) and updating the `content`dictionary with a new record corresponding to each user.

Then, after asking for credentials, we just look the given username in our `content` dictionary and check that the password is the same.

Comment: Revilscano,

Thank you so much. I will admit, I am a beginner and I have learnt some new things in those few lines of code, which are extremely efficient.

Comment: No problem, if I can clarify anything else you want from my answer, I'll be glad to help you

Comment: I will do actually, but first let me do some reading up on some of the stuff you have used there and try to understand the logic. Will definitely bug you with more questions :D

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to modify the for loop a bit and it works for me. Take a look.

```python
i = 0; login = 0 #Here login is like a flag. Which get the value 1 once the login is successful else stays 0.
while i < len(username_list):
    if username == str(username_list[i]) and password == str(password_list[i]):
        login = 1
        print('''Please select one of the following options:
                r - register user
                a - add task
                va - view all tasks
                vm - view my tasks
                e - exit''')
        break
    i+=1
    if i==len(username_list) and login == 0:
        print("invalid username or password")   
        username = input("Please enter username: ")
        password = input("Please enter password: ")
        i = 0
```

The second if condition in the for loop checks if the login is not successful for all the values in the lists, it means the username and passwords are incorrect, so the if condition asks for the new inputs and resets the while loop to start again from 0.